# Get height of Custom UITableViewCell working with different UIStoryboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have different `UIStoryboards` for different devices in a project where I don't use `Auto Layout`. Inside an `UITableViewController` I have two different `UITableViewCells` with different height. I am trying to load the height with following lines in `viewDidLoad`

```
ProfileCell *profilCell = 
 (ProfileCell *)[self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"profileCell"];
fProfileHeight = profilCell.frame.size.height;

MenuCell *menuCell = 
 (MenuCell *)[self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"menuCell"];
fMenuHeight = menuCell.frame.size.height;
```

The problem is, it doesn't match with the values I set inside the `UIStoryboard`. `CellIdentifier` is also set, and content is presented correctly, I just can't load the exact `tableRowHeight`. Does anybody know what I can do? I also searched for this problem but I couldn't find anything suitable for my problem. I also don't have any nibs otherwise I could load the height from nib-file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your cell into Xib Interface file, after that

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       MenuCell *cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuCell"
                                                       owner:nil
                                                     options:nil] firstObject];
       return cell.frame.size.height;
}
```

Also after placing into Xib, you need to register Nib as a reusable cell.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];
      [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MenuCell" bundle:nil]
           forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MenuCell"];
}
```

Comment: Like I wrote in my post, I know about the solution with nib files... but I don't have any. I want to know if there is a solution to get the height of the `UITableViewCell` directly inside my code